# How to execute emacs grep-find link in the same window?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

When I use `grep`-`find` it opens another window (area in the frame) with a list of results that I can select. When I select one it opens the target file in a different window than `grep`-`find` is in.

How can I get the target file to open in the same window as the `grep` results (replacing the `grep` results window with what I am actually looking for).

How can I keep grep-find from opening a separate window (have it so it opens in the current window). My goal is I look for something, I find it, I go to it, all within the same window. I would like to add this to my `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is any way to configure the `compile` package to do what you're asking.  And there's no easy way to use [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Defining-Advice.html) to tweak the behavior.  I think you have to resort to editing the function which actually jumps to the error, which you can do with the following addition to your .emacs (tested in Emacs 23.1):

```
(eval-after-load "compile"
'(defun compilation-goto-locus (msg mk end-mk)
  "Jump to an error corresponding to MSG at MK.
All arguments are markers.  If END-MK is non-nil, mark is set there
and overlay is highlighted between MK and END-MK."
  ;; Show compilation buffer in other window, scrolled to this error.
  (let* ((from-compilation-buffer (eq (window-buffer (selected-window))
                  (marker-buffer msg)))
     ;; Use an existing window if it is in a visible frame.
     (pre-existing (get-buffer-window (marker-buffer msg) 0))
     (w (if (and from-compilation-buffer pre-existing)
        ;; Calling display-buffer here may end up (partly) hiding
        ;; the error location if the two buffers are in two
        ;; different frames.  So don't do it if it's not necessary.
        pre-existing
      (let ((display-buffer-reuse-frames t)
        (pop-up-windows t))
        ;; Pop up a window.
        (display-buffer (marker-buffer msg)))))
     (highlight-regexp (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer msg)
             ;; also do this while we change buffer
             (compilation-set-window w msg)
             compilation-highlight-regexp)))
;; Ideally, the window-size should be passed to `display-buffer' (via
;; something like special-display-buffer) so it's only used when
;; creating a new window.
(unless pre-existing (compilation-set-window-height w))

(switch-to-buffer (marker-buffer mk))

    ;; was
;; (if from-compilation-buffer
;;     ;; If the compilation buffer window was selected,
;;     ;; keep the compilation buffer in this window;
;;     ;; display the source in another window.
;;     (let ((pop-up-windows t))
;;       (pop-to-buffer (marker-buffer mk) 'other-window))
;;   (if (window-dedicated-p (selected-window))
;;       (pop-to-buffer (marker-buffer mk))
;;     (switch-to-buffer (marker-buffer mk))))
;; If narrowing gets in the way of going to the right place, widen.
(unless (eq (goto-char mk) (point))
  (widen)
  (goto-char mk))
(if end-mk
    (push-mark end-mk t)
  (if mark-active (setq mark-active)))
;; If hideshow got in the way of
;; seeing the right place, open permanently.
(dolist (ov (overlays-at (point)))
  (when (eq 'hs (overlay-get ov 'invisible))
    (delete-overlay ov)
    (goto-char mk)))

(when highlight-regexp
  (if (timerp next-error-highlight-timer)
      (cancel-timer next-error-highlight-timer))
  (unless compilation-highlight-overlay
    (setq compilation-highlight-overlay
      (make-overlay (point-min) (point-min)))
    (overlay-put compilation-highlight-overlay 'face 'next-error))
  (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer mk)
    (save-excursion
      (if end-mk (goto-char end-mk) (end-of-line))
      (let ((end (point)))
    (if mk (goto-char mk) (beginning-of-line))
    (if (and (stringp highlight-regexp)
         (re-search-forward highlight-regexp end t))
        (progn
          (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
          (move-overlay compilation-highlight-overlay
                (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                (current-buffer)))
      (move-overlay compilation-highlight-overlay
            (point) end (current-buffer)))
    (if (or (eq next-error-highlight t)
        (numberp next-error-highlight))
        ;; We want highlighting: delete overlay on next input.
        (add-hook 'pre-command-hook
              'compilation-goto-locus-delete-o)
      ;; We don't want highlighting: delete overlay now.
      (delete-overlay compilation-highlight-overlay))
    ;; We want highlighting for a limited time:
    ;; set up a timer to delete it.
    (when (numberp next-error-highlight)
      (setq next-error-highlight-timer
        (run-at-time next-error-highlight nil
                 'compilation-goto-locus-delete-o)))))))
(when (and (eq next-error-highlight 'fringe-arrow))
  ;; We want a fringe arrow (instead of highlighting).
  (setq next-error-overlay-arrow-position
    (copy-marker (line-beginning-position)))))))
```

The `eval-afer-load` portion just ensures that you re-define it *after* Emacs defined it, so that your change takes hold.

Comment: Trey, Is it possible to tweak your function to have Shift-mouse click open in same buffer versus keeping the same mouse click behavior to open in a separate window?

Comment: @Ammari Not trivially.  The hack approach would be to have a new binding for Shift-mouse to locally set a variable `(let ((use-same-window t)) ...)` and then issue the command to jump to the error, and in the function above, choose which behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a binding (e.g. Alt-m) and do the following

```
(define-key grep-mode-map "\M-m" (lambda() 
                                   (interactive) 
                                   (compile-goto-error)
                                   (delete-other-windows)
                                   (kill-buffer "*grep*")))
```

I didn't find a way to replace the standard "Enter" / Mouse-click binding with a custom function

Comment: the standard enter/mouse-click binding is a text property of that substring of the buffer, you could edit that property, or change the way that compile adds that property

Answer (score 1):

There is an another approach:

```
(defun eab/compile-goto-error ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((cwc (current-window-configuration)))
    (funcall
     `(lambda ()
        (defun eab/compile-goto-error-internal ()
          (let ((cb (current-buffer))
                (p (point)))
            (set-window-configuration ,cwc)
            (switch-to-buffer cb)
            (goto-char p ))))))
  (compile-goto-error)
  (run-with-timer 0.01 nil 'eab/compile-goto-error-internal))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and found this answer over at emacs.stackexchange https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33908/20000

```
(defun my-compile-goto-error-same-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action
         '((display-buffer-reuse-window
            display-buffer-same-window)
           (inhibit-same-window . nil))))
    (call-interactively #'compile-goto-error)))

(defun my-compilation-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "o") #'my-compile-goto-error-same-window))

(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook #'my-compilation-mode-hook)
```

Pressing `o` in the `*grep*` buffer will open the location and file in the same frame.

I found this an elegant solution without deleting frames or too much lisp code and just hooking into `compilation-mode-hook`.