# Want compile-goto-error variant that replaces compilation buffer in current window

Tags: elisp

I have a personal elisp function that performs an multi-directory grep. It uses `compilation-start`, which creates a compilation-mode buffer with the results, in which I can press `RET` (bound to `compile-goto-error`) to jump to the corresponding location.

However, `compile-goto-error` always visits the location in another window, leaving the compilation buffer up. Half the time I am just searching for one particular location, so what I would like to do is bind some other key (say `C-RET`) to also visit the corresponding location in a buffer, but stay in the current window, replacing the compilation buffer with the location's buffer.

I've traced the relevant execution from `compile-goto-error` to `next-error-internal` to `next-error-function` to `compilation-next-error-function` to `compilation-find-file`, but can't find a nice place to hook in my differing behavior. Is there a simple way (or, failing that, a complicated one) to create a `compile-goto-error` variant that switches to the new buffer in-place in the window that held the compilation buffer?

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31746371/1937596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to get what you want by let-binding `display-buffer-overriding-action`, something like:

```
(defun my-next-error ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-same-window)))
    (next-error)))
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be changing the behavior for me. I added some `(message)` statements to `display-buffer` and I can see that it is being called when I execute `my-next-error`, and that it sees `display-buffer-overriding-action` as being `'(display-buffer-same-window))`, but the buffer still shows up in a different window. Perhaps it has already chosen the new window by the time it decides to display the buffer?

Comment: The hypothesis at the end of my last question was incorrect. I used `message` to show the `(window-edges)` of the selected window inside `display-buffer`, and that identifies it as the compilation window.

Comment: The problem was that `compilation-goto-locus` explicitly calls `pop-to-buffer` with the action `other-window`, and as a result `display-buffer` passes `inhibit-same-window` to `display-buffer-same-window`, preventing it from running. I created a new function `display-buffer-same-window-override` that is like `display-buffer-same-window` but which does not respect `inhibit-same-window`, and use that for my `display-buffer-overriding-action` in this case, which achieves the desired behavior.

Comment: Then I think that `(let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-same-window (inhibit-same-window . nil)))) (next-error)))` might also work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest just advising the `compile-goto-error` function to do the right thing, rather than creating a custom function and keybinding. The following does the right thing for me (following Stefan's suggestion):

```
(defadvice compile-goto-error (around my-compile-goto-error activate)
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-reuse-window (inhibit-same-window . nil))))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: Well, I want to keep the regular `compile-goto-error` around as well, since I sometimes do want to bring it up in a separate window. I ended up with a solution similar to Stefan's.